# Import Angular custom Library dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an application and 4 custom angular libraries, depending on the customer to whom I have to release my application I must enable or disable the libraries.
The libraries are used to implement a dashboard in my application
as if they were plugins.
Example for customer 1 I will use 3 libraries, for customer 2 he will use 1 library etc etc.

Is it possible, perhaps by placing the library build in the dist folder, to read only those present in that folder?

I'm using Angular 14.

Before updating to angular 14 we imported the "umd" file, present in the bundle folder of the library, in the dist folder of the application and then with SystemJS we read the file and loaded the library module. Now due to a series of errors I can no longer import as before